# Give type as argument like va_arg in C

Tags: c, types, variadic-functions

`va_arg(a,type)` macro expands to `__builtin_va_arg(a,type)` which is built-in part of compiler.

Is it possible to implement type based functionality, if yes how?

Comment: Not really (except for macro tricks). What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: In mingw it isn't macro trick, but compiler built-in

Comment: @user2175249 and that built-in works as same as MACROs.

Comment: @MM. The compiler built-in is actually smarter than macros, for some target hardware.  Some systems pass floating point values widened to `double`s in FPU registers when possible, rather than on the stack.  If `sizeof(double)` is 8 (as it often is) and something else (`long long`) is also 8 bytes, you need some kind of compiler magic to do the right thing.  (See SPARC and MIPS systems for example.)  Of course if all arguments go on one single stack, it's easy(ish) to handle with a macro.

Comment: @torek: You're right. But I'm talking as a programer who uses `__builtin_va_arg`, not a programer who wrote it. In my view, I can just say it's like a well known MACRO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Notice that [va_arg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_arg/) cannot determine the actual type of the
>   argument passed to the function, but uses whatever type is passed as
>   the type macro argument as its type.

Lets see how `va_arg` works, one possibility from [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/invisible/include/stdarg.h.htm), is

```
#define va_arg(ap,t) (*(t *)((ap += _INTSIZEOF(t)) - _INTSIZEOF(t)))
```

First of all, it's a MACRO not a function.

If you want write a type base MACRO as same as `var_arg`, you have two main tools, *`pointers`* and *`sizeof`*.

You can increase/decrease/lookup  a pointer with `sizeof` steps.

Answer (score 3):

With the preprocessor, you can indeed implement type based functionality, although it is limited. Don't forget that `#define` directives act with copy/paste, so you can not compare types in C standard, for instance(*).

However, you can reuse a `type` argument to build type-generic functions. Here is an example of a `min` generic function:

```
#define DEFINE_MIN(type)        \
int min_##type(type a, type b)  \
{ return a < b ? a : b; }
```

By the way, a `gcc` extension, `typeof`, gives the type of an expression (it doesn't rely on the programmer arguments anymore). Moreover, more recently, the C11 `_Generic` keyword permits you to write different treatment for expressions of different types.

(*) In the case of `va_arg`, the `type` argument is often use to get the size of `type` and `type*`.